# Standard problem explaining how CDF works

Tags: probability

I just want to know if I solved the problem right. $$F_X(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } t <0 \\ \frac{1}{7}, & \mbox{if } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{14}\\ \frac{2}{7}+t, & \mbox{if } \frac{1}{14}\leq t < \frac{3}{7}\\ 1, & \mbox{if } t\geq\frac{3}{7} \end{cases}\ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Find $\mathbb{P}(0<X<\frac{3}{7})$, $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$ and $\mathbb{E}X$

Solution:

So, $\mathbb{P}(0<X<\frac{3}{7})=\lim_{t\to^-\frac{3}{7}}F_X(t)-\lim_{t\to^+0}F_X(t)=\frac{2}{7}+\frac{3}{7}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{4}{7}$

$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=F_X(0)-\lim_{t\to^-0}F_X(t)=\frac{1}{7}-0=\frac{1}{7}$

$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E [X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \,\mathrm d F_X (x) \\
&= \int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm d F_X (x) +\int_{-\infty}^0 x \mathrm d F_X (x) \\
&= \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t)) \,\mathrm d t - \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(t)\,\mathrm d t.\\
&= \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t)) \,\mathrm d t
\\&=\frac{6}{7}t\Big|^\frac{1}{14}_0+\Big[\frac{5}{7}t+-\frac{1}{2}t^2\Big]\Big|^\frac{3}{7}_\frac{1}{14}+0
\\&=\frac{89}{392}\end{align*}$

Comment: as opposed to discrete random variables is that the CDF is a continuous function, i.e., it does not have any jumps. Remember that jumps in the CDF correspond to points x for which $P(X=x)>0$ . Thus, the fact that the CDF does not have jumps is consistent with the fact that $P(X=x)=0$ for all x.

Comment: @emonhossain Right, that one has jumps though.